# how to get facebook friends list in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-friends

i have user_friends permission when user authenticates and i tried a lot to get friends list from facebook

this is my call

```
       /* make the API call */
        new Request(
                session,
                "/me/taggable_friends" /*"/me/friendlists"*/  /*"/"+id+"/friends"*/ /*"/me/friends"*/,
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
       /* handle the result */
                        Log.d(TAG, "friends list request response:" + response.getRawResponse());

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

i got friends list only with the account i have created the facebook id
if tried with another new account it just giving the count but NO DATA

can any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

[developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) : "Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app"

Right now you can set       `Settings.setPlatformCompatibilityEnabled(true);` and it will work but soon Fb will disable that.